# legend() is empty for contour plot; is this by design?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, contour

I wrote

```
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(2. / 3.))
ax = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
cs = ax.contour(X, Y, distances_bulk, 8)
plt.sca(ax)
plt.legend()
```

and got

[image]

i.e. small empty thing at upper right corner instead of a legend (marked by red triangle by me). Is this by design? How to get a legend (i.e. with values) for contour plot?

Python is 3.7 or 3.8, matplotlib is 3.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the writers of matplotlib expect the levels to be put inline, instead of the legend. See [Contour Demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-contour-demo-py).

That being said, the object returned by `contour` contains a reference to the artists and the level values, so you can use that to create the legend:

```
delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=7)

h = CS.collections
l = [f'{a:.1f}' for a in CS.levels]
ax.legend(h,l)
```

[image]

Comment: A simpler approach is  `h, l = CS.legend_elements()`, which already creates appropriate labels.