# How to plot a function ax^2+bxy+cy^2+d=0 in Python?

Tags: python

I have a function in the form of `ax^2+bxy+cy^2+d=0`. This one can be written as `f(x,y) = 0`. I tried to write a code to plot the function in the x,y-plane as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x,y):
    return 0.01*x**2+0.008*x*y-0.013*y**2+0.15*x+0.003*y+1.0097

x = np.arange(-10.0,10.0,0.1)
y = np.arange(-10.0,10.0,0.1)
plt.plot(x, f(x, y));
```

[image: wrong graph]

But I only got a 1D graph of my function. I want the graph where `f(x,y)` takes the value `0`.

Comment: You forgot to add the error

Comment: What do you mean by "plot in 2D"? What is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: What's your error since this works for me?

Comment: @DarrylG Sorry, the graph is more like a line but not a curve... I do not know how to modify it.

Comment: @MihailFeraru Please see my edit.

Comment: I get a curve. Also your x-axis is different (I get -10 to 10) which is the range of the x values.

Comment: [Works fine for me...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLsPV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your function with 2D coordinates you can evaluate it with a grid of `x` and `y` values created with [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html). To draw the graph as a 2D function you can use [`plt.contour`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) and set the levels to the function value you are interested in

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x,y):
    return 0.01*x**2+0.008*x*y-0.013*y**2+0.15*x+0.003*y+1.0097

x = np.arange(-10.0,10.0,0.1)
y = np.arange(-10.0,10.0,0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
plt.contour(x, y, f(X, Y), [0]);
```

Output

[image: f(x)]

Comment: Thanks. But why your graph is different from mine?

Comment: Can I ask what does parameter '[0]' mean in 'plt.contour(x, y, f(X, Y), [0])'?

Comment: It's the parameter `levels=[0]` *If array-like, draw contour lines at the specified levels. The values must be in increasing order.* from `plt.contour`[documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html)

Comment: Can I ask how to add a label for this curve in `plt.contour'? Like using `plt.legend()` Thanks.

Comment: For example, `plt.contour(x, y, f(X, Y), [0], label='class 1`)``

Comment: You can add the level label to the contour line with `cs = plt.contour(x, y, f(X, Y), [0]); plt.clabel(cs, fmt='%.1f');`. There is no `label` or `name` parameter for `plt.contour`. Solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490302/how-do-you-create-a-legend-for-a-contour-plot-in-matplotlib) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64523051/legend-is-empty-for-contour-plot-is-this-by-design).