# How to add a legend entry for a curve in contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, contour

Based on this question, [How to plot a function ax^2+bxy+cy^2+d=0 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69241498/how-to-plot-a-function-ax2bxycy2d-0-in-python). I cite code from @Michael Szczesny's answer:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x,y):
    return 0.01*x**2+0.008*x*y-0.013*y**2+0.15*x+0.003*y+1.0097

x = np.arange(-10.0,10.0,0.1)
y = np.arange(-10.0,10.0,0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
plt.contour(x, y, f(X, Y), [0]);
```

If I try to add a label for curve `f(X,Y)`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x,y):
    return 0.01*x**2+0.008*x*y-0.013*y**2+0.15*x+0.003*y+1.0097

x = np.arange(-10.0,10.0,0.1)
y = np.arange(-10.0,10.0,0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
plt.contour(x, y, f(X, Y), [0], label='class 1')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Error: UserWarning: The following kwargs were not used by contour:

Comment: There is a typo in ``'class 1'``. And this is how to add label to a contour plot https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-pyplot-clabel-in-python/amp/

Comment: try this: `fig, ax = plt.subplots();cntr = ax.contour(x, y, f(X, Y));ax.clabel(cntr)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib's [`contour`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html) seems to be designed with the idea of drawing a colorbar instead of a legend. However, in this case, with only one level, a legend can be forced assigning a label to individual contours:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x, y):
    return 0.01 * x ** 2 + 0.008 * x * y - 0.013 * y ** 2 + 0.15 * x + 0.003 * y + 1.0097

x = np.arange(-10.0, 10.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-10.0, 10.0, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
cnt = plt.contour(x, y, f(X, Y), [0])
cnt.collections[0].set_label('class 1')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.contour with legend]

Here is an example of the same approach with multiple levels:

```py
levels = [0, 1, 2, 3]
cnt = plt.contour(x, y, f(X, Y), levels)
for level, contour in zip(levels, cnt.collections):
    contour.set_label('level {level}')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[1.01, 1], loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.contour with legend for multiple contours]

Answer (score 4):

The [answer from 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69296064/2148614) no longer works on Matplotlib 3.5.2. It will not render correctly:

[image]

[image]

Instead, we should use `legend_elements` with custom labels:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x, y):
    return 0.01 * x ** 2 + 0.008 * x * y - 0.013 * y ** 2 + 0.15 * x + 0.003 * y + 1.0097

x = np.arange(-10.0, 10.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-10.0, 10.0, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
cnt = plt.contour(x, y, f(X, Y), [0])
artists, labels = cnt.legend_elements()
plt.legend(artists, ['class 1'])
plt.show()

# multiple levels
levels = [0, 1, 2, 3]
cnt = plt.contour(x, y, f(X, Y), levels)
artists, labels = cnt.legend_elements()
custom_labels = []
for level, contour in zip(levels, cnt.collections):
    custom_labels.append(f'level {level}')
plt.legend(artists, custom_labels, bbox_to_anchor=[1.01, 1], loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

It will produce the correct result:

[image]

[image]