# sample lines in the legend box disappeared by contour plot with specific levels

Tags: matplotlib

I tried to add legend on a specific level by contour plot using matplotlib and the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

x0 = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
y0 = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x0,y0)

cs0 = ax[0].contour(x, y, x**2 + y**2, [1,2,3])
h = cs0.collections
l0 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
ax[0].legend(h, l0)# <-
#ax[0].legend()

cs1 = ax[1].contour(x, y, x**2 + y**2 ,[1,2,3])
l2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
for i, l in enumerate(l2):
    cs1.collections[i].set_label(l)
ax[1].legend()
plt.savefig("abc.png")
plt.show()
```

However, sample lines are missing on the legend box. In addition, The following code induces improper lines behind the axes.

```
ax[0].legend(h, l0)# <-
```

[image]

I can find that someone achieved my goal on the web, but I cannot do this.

[legend() is empty for contour plot; is this by design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64523051/legend-is-empty-for-contour-plot-is-this-by-design)

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11134

Could you please comment on what am I wrong, thank you.

My environment is macOSX apple silicon (M1)  and python environment is miniforge3

```
% python
Python 3.9.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, May 27 2022, 17:00:33)
[Clang 13.0.1 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'3.5.2'
```

My matplotlibrc is the default. The problem cannot resolve with the latest anaconda 3.

Comment: TRY this: `handles, labels = cs0.legend_elements();ax[0].legend(handles, l0)`

Comment: Thank you very much!! My problem is completely solved!!