# Legend for contourf in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, legend

Is there a way put a legend for a contourf plot in matplotlib?
In matlab it's possible to put one like the example picture shown below.

I am aware of both these questions posted previously:

[How do you create a legend for a contour plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490302/how-do-you-create-a-legend-for-a-contour-plot)

[legend() is empty for contour plot; is this by design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64523051/legend-is-empty-for-contour-plot-is-this-by-design)

They both add a legend for each contour level, Instead I want a single legend entry (again, like the one in the snapshot below).
I tried `ax.contourf(x,y,z,levels=10,label="myplot"`, but got a warning that the `label` keyword was not used.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.[image: Contourf plot with legend]

Comment: I agree this is not a duplicate of the other question.  Since I thought it was an interesting question, I put a possible solution in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/rcomer/8865353da4d1bccdac5d51a11b25f504).

Comment: @RuthC This is what I'm looking for, thanks! (I guess if you answer it I can accept it as a solution).

Comment: Glad it helped!  Since the question was closed, unfortunately I can’t post an answer.

Answer (score -1):

color visualization be done using a proxy artist

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np

# Create sample data
x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.cos(X) + np.sin(Y)

# Create the contour plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
contour = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=10)

# Create a proxy artist for the legend
proxy = [mpatches.Patch(color=pc.get_facecolor()[0]) for pc in contour.collections]

# Create the legend
plt.legend(proxy, [f'Level {i+1}' for i in range(len(contour.levels))], loc='upper right', title='Legend')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Although the question asks for a legend, it is also very common to use a [colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_log.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-contourf-log-py) in this situation, which can show either a gradient or discrete levels.

Comment: Sorry, but neither answer answers my question. I am not looking for a legend for each level, and I'm not looking for a colorbar. I'm looking for a single legend entry associated with the contour/contourf (as shown in the example image).

Comment: Note also that the `collections` attribute is deprecated in Matplotlib v3.8, so this code will fail in future.